# Why is my code displaying letter by letter instead of word by word?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a basic interpreter but the way the output in the datagrid is shown is letter by letter instead of word by word. See the pics.
[wrong way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nijrr.png)
[right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msES8.png)

This is what I got so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim nro_letras As Integer 
Dim cont As Integer 
Dim cadena As String 
Dim conversion As String 
Dim palabras As String 


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    cont = 0 
    For atun As Integer = 1 To nro_letras 
        conversion = Mid(cadena, atun, 1)

        Select Case Asc(conversion)
            Case 0 To 32
                MsgBox("este caracter no es valido")
            Case Is >= 125
                MsgBox("este caracter no es valido")
            Case Else
                palabras = palabras & conversion
        End Select

        If DataGridView1.RowCount = cont Then DataGridView1.Rows.Add()


        DataGridView1.Item(0, cont).Value = cont
        DataGridView1.Item(1, cont).Value = palabras


        cont += 1
        palabras = ""

    Next
    cont += 1

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    nro_letras = TextBox1.TextLength 'Digo que el numero de letras es todo lo que usuario escriba'
    cadena = TextBox1.Text 'lo que esta escrito en el textbox es mi string'
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have a For loop that looks at every single character in the string.  It calls Rows.Add() inside the loop.  It does *exactly* what you programmed it to do.  You'll have to parse words instead of characters, a much fuzzier definition but String.Split() ought to get you somewhere.

Comment: This is not VBA, it's VB.Net. VBA is used in MS Office applications such as Word and Excel, not Visual Studio. I've corrected the tags. Please learn what language you're using and tag appropriately in the future. It would also be beneficial to you to learn to use the debugger, which would have allowed you to figure this out yourself faster than you could copy and paste the code here.

Comment: My bad fixed the tag @KenWhite

Answer (score 1):

Hans is right, it's doing what you told it to. To get the row to have the entire word you'd need to put the current code for Sub for Button1_Click inside an additional loop. To give you a start

1. Like Hans said you should parse the original text. Do so into an
   array
2. Iterate through the words in the array
3. On each character, do the character analysis you're currently doing
4. Be sure to handle the case of a failure of a character (right now it looks like you'll just be missing the failed character(s), but that doesn't seem to
   line up with your intent)